# Можно ли в JComboBox при нажатии на кнопку выбрать следующую строку(item)?

Tags: java

И как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Может, есть метод и получше, но вижу такой вариант: повесить обработчик нажатия на кнопку и через методы getSelectedIndex() и setSelectedItem() менять выбранную строку. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

Comment: Это наверное единственный верный путь!